# ¿Como obtengo todos los elementos que tengan una clase? por jQuery

Tags: jquery

Obtengo los elementos bien por **javascript** pero no por **jQuery** y los necesito por **jQuery**.

Por **javascript** los obtengo de esta manera:

```
let all = document.querySelectorAll('.botonEstado');
console.log(all);
```

Y efectivamente me da el resultado.

Por **jQuery** intento de esta manera:

```
var all = $(".mbox").map(function() {
    return this.innerHTML;
}).get();
console.log(all.join());
```

Pero no obtengo nada.

He hecho el intento basado en [**esta pregunta**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630211/jquery-get-all-elements-by-class-name) en Stack Overflow.

Comment: Es posible que agregues un snippet con el ejemplo del codigo que intentas acceder?

Comment: Como menciono en [mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/93094/65), el código jQuery funciona bien. Agrega un [mcve] para entender mejor que es lo que está pasando con lo que has intentado.

Comment: Por la cantidad de respuestas, creo que está bien claro la pregunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) el cual:

> Sirve para iterar sobre un objeto jQuery, ejecutando una función para
>   cada elemento coincidente.
>
> El método `.each()` está diseñado para que las construcciones de
>   bucles DOM sean concisas y menos propensas a errores. Cuando se llama,
>   itera sobre los elementos DOM que forman parte del objeto jQuery. Cada
>   vez que se ejecuta la devolución de llamada, se pasa la iteración del
>   bucle actual, empezando por 0. Más importante aún, la devolución de
>   llamada se activa en el contexto del elemento DOM actual, por lo que
>   la palabra clave `this` se refiere al elemento.

Por ejemplo:

```js
$(function() {

  $(".mbox").each(function(index) {
      console.log(index + ": " + $(this).text());
      console.log($(this).attr('id'));
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="mbox">
  <p id="p1">Lorem<span> <em>impsum</em></span></p>
  <ul>
    <li>Uno</li>
    <li>Dos</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="div2" class="mbox">
  <blockquote>Lorem impsum dolor sit amet</blockquote>
</div>


<div class="no-mbox">
  <ul>
    <li>Tres</li>
    <li>Cuatro</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="div3" class="mbox">
  <ul>
    <li>Cinco</li>
    <li>Seis</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Codigo

```js
var elementos = $(".boton").map(function() {
  return $(this).html();
}).get();

console.log(elementos);
```

```css
.boton {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.elemento {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  color: #2980b9;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="boton">
  <a>UNO</a>
</div>
<div class="boton">
  <a>DOS</a>
</div>
<div class="elemento">
  <a>TRES</a>
</div>
<div class="boton">
  <a>CUATRO</a>
</div>
```

---

### Explicación

Revisando lo que propones, acerca de obtener elementos usando un **[selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)** basado en el nombre de la clase, he podido encontrar lo siguiente:

- Uso de `$(this)` para acceder al elemento
- En lugar de usar el parametro `.innerHTML` usar el metodo [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) de jQuery.

Quiza sea este algun problema de incompatibilidad en el navegador donde estes ejecutando el codigo, porque si intentas de otra forma:

```js
var elementos = $(".boton").map(function() {
  return this.innerHTML;
}).get();

console.log(elementos);
```

```css
.boton {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.elemento {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  color: #2980b9;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="boton">
  <a>UNO</a>
</div>
<div class="boton">
  <a>DOS</a>
</div>
<div class="elemento">
  <a>TRES</a>
</div>
<div class="boton">
  <a>CUATRO</a>
</div>
```

Si te fijas obtendras el mismo resultado que obtienes usando el metodo **[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** de jQuery.

> **Nota:** debes tener en cuenta que si estas obteniendo el innerHTML de un elemento, obtendras la cadena literal de html de lo que se encuentre ADENTRO del elemento, en ejemplo he usado `<a>` y el innerHTML nos devolvera el texto contenido entre los `<a>`, pero si necesitas obtener toda la composicion del elemento, puedes usar `outerHTML`.

---

### Actualizacion

Si lo que necesitas es acceder a cada una de las propiedades del elemento en HTML, seria tambien util usar **[.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)**:

```js
$(".boton").each(function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "red");
}).get();
```

```css
.boton {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.elemento {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  color: #2980b9;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="boton">
  <a>UNO</a>
</div>
<div class="boton">
  <a>DOS</a>
</div>
<div class="elemento">
  <a>TRES</a>
</div>
<div class="boton">
  <a>CUATRO</a>
</div>
```

En este ejemplo hemos referenciado a cada uno de los nodos html, accediendo directamente a ellos a traves de jQuery y hemos modificado el color de fondo que tenia inicialmente.

Answer (score 1):

**Haga eso:**

    `$(".botonEstado").each(function( index ) {
      //index <= del array
      //$(this) <= boton actual
      console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
    });`

**Por ejemplo:**

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

$(".botonEstado").each(function( index ) {
  //index <= del array
  //$(this) <= boton actual
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Boton Estado</title>
</head>

<body>
<button class="botonEstado" type="button">estado 1</button>
<button class="botonEstado" type="button">estado 2</button>
<button class="botonEstado" type="button">estado 3</button>
<button class="botonEstado" type="button">estado 4</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Depende lo que quieras hacer con los elementos puedes usar simplemente

```
$('.botonEstado');
```

que sería similar a

```
document.querySelectorAll('.botonEstado');
```

pero pudiendo actuar sobre todos los elemento a la vez sin tener que iterarlos, por ejemplo si quisieras darles a todos un color de fondo:

```js
$('.botonEstado').css("background","yellow")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="botonEstado">elemento seleccionado</div>
<div class="botonEstado">elemento seleccionado</div>
<div class="">no seleccionado</div>
<div class="botonEstado">elemento seleccionado</div>
<div class="botonEstado">elemento seleccionado</div>
<div class="">no seleccionado</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

El código del OP funciona bien, al menos en Stack Snippet, así que probablemente el error sea la versión de jQuery o que olvidó cargar jQuery

Demostración:

```js
var all = $(".mbox").map(function() {
    return this.innerHTML;
}).get();

console.log(all.join());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mbox">Block One</div>
<div class="mbox">Block Two</div>
<div class="mbox">Block Three</div>
<div class="mbox">Block Four</div>

<p></p>
```